# Trying to compile with codelite

Tags: c++, c, compilation, codelite

I have just downloaded this [tarball](http://libtheoraplayer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libtheoraplayer/trunk/)...Now I wan to compile it cos I found a readme in *trunk/projects/gcc* that says this:

> The Linux GCC and Windows MinGW builds in this project are supported
>   via a CodeLite project file. Codelite is a very cool open source C++
>   IDE, it can be found here: http://www.codelite.org/ Other GCC build
>   methods aren't actively supported but contributors and maintainers are
>   welcome to do so! Just drop me a line and I'll see about adding you to
>   the project's svn write access list.

So I installed codelite 3.5 and opened the *trunk/projects/gcc/libtheoraplayer.workspace* with codelite but when I try to run the project (play button) nothing happens..any idea?

**Anyway, if anyone knows how to compile that tarball in other way I will be pleased to use it..I tried it using configure-make but i didnt get it..**

Ubuntu 11.10

Javier

Comment: Stupid question, but have you compiled it first? The play button only runs the program; it won't compile automatically before running, unless you change the settings to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the library you're trying to compile.
The problem is, I have previously used CodeLite but have since stopped and hence removed all CodeLite project files.
This is because I don't have enough time to maintain them next to other more important project files.

If you're interested in maintaining codelite files for this project please post on the project's forum, I'll guide you into setting up the files and preprocessor macros.

Project page link: http://libtheoraplayer.cateia.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page